# delete item in sqlite database with cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I have a cursor that filled my database and i would like to delete the elements from this table.

her is the removal code fro my database:

```
public void deleteItem(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    database.delete(ContractParaGastos.GASTO, ContractParaGastos.Columnas.MONTO + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    database.close();
}
```

And here is the removal code in recyclerviewAdapter:

```
 viewHolder.button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           databaseHelper.deleteItem(i);
        }
    });
}
```

I add this line in my adapter:

```
 databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context, ContractParaGastos.GASTO, null, 4);
```

But when i click on the delete button nothing happens. the line is still present in my recyclerview.

Help me please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you didn't initialised the `databaseHelper`.

**Try this code:**

```
   DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this); //in case of activity.
   DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()); //in case of Fragment.
```

Paste this code in `onCreate() of Activity` or `onCreateView() of Fragment`.

Thanks and let me know if some need to know more.

Comment: I add this in my MainActivitybut i have the same error.

Comment: Please update you question with activity class and database helper class

Comment: I did it. if you need anything else please let me know!

Comment: ContractParaGastos.GASTO is it your table name, right??..why you are passing this as your database name??

Comment: @mavis send me on my I'd ankitpatidar030@gmail.com

Comment: OK that's fine.

Comment: i just sent him!

Comment: Hey Mavis you there??

Answer (score 0):

from the little code you provided I would check that the variable i in: 
    databaseHelper.deleteItem(i);
represents really an existing id of the record I need to delete.